# PHP mysql PDO extend class error

Tags: php, mysql, oop, pdo

Im new to OOP and Im going to work with simple php,mysql wrapper class. Im unable to call a public function it gives me a error. Im unable to figure it out!!

```
<?php 
class db extends PDO {

    private $error;
    private $sql;
    private $bind;
    private $errorCallbackFunction;
    private $errorMsgFormat;

    public function __construct($dsn, $user="", $passwd="") {

        $options = array(
             PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true, 
             PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
        );

        try {
             parent::__construct($dsn, $user, $passwd, $options);
        } 
        catch (PDOException $e) {
             $this->error = $e->getMessage();
        }
    }

    public function test() {
         echo 'whats wrong with this!!!';
    }

}   

$d = new db("mysql:host=127.0.0.1;port=8889;dbname=weddingplan", "root", "");
$d->test(); ?>
```

and Result of my xampp server is

> Warning: Creating default object from empty value in C:\xampp\htdocs\newwedding\models\class.db.php on line 18
>
> Fatal error: Call to a member function test() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\newwedding\models\class.db.php on line 32

Can you please teel me how to call a public function test ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The explanation of what's going wrong here is a little long-winded, so bear with me.

In your child class (db)'s constructor, you explicitly call the parent class (PDO)'s constructor:

```
try {
    parent::__construct($dsn, $user, $passwd, $options);
```

but that call is throwing an exception, which you catch:

```
} catch (PDOException $e) {
```

and then you try to set a property of the object:

```
    $this->error = $e->getMessage();
}
```

but `$this` hasn't been instantiated (because the parent constructor failed!)—so it's no longer a special reference to the current object, but rather PHP treats it like any other variable (and the attempt to assign to its `error` property causes PHP to instantiate a default object of `\stdClass` to `$this` instead); hence the rather cryptic warning:

> Warning: Creating default object from empty value in C:\xampp\htdocs\newwedding\models\class.db.php on line 18

Frankly, this behaviour is insane and PHP really should do something far more sane like bail out at that point, but nevertheless it proceeds...

```
$d = new db("mysql:host=127.0.0.1;port=8889;dbname=weddingplan", "root", "");
```

...but since this attempt to instantiate a `db` object failed, `$d` is null.  And then the attempt to call `$d->test()` obviously fails with the error that you see:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function test() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\newwedding\models\class.db.php on line 32

So, what should you do to fix it?  Well, you could investigate why the invocation of the PDO constructor failed (probably incorrect database connection details) and correct that; you could even handle the exception better so that errors of this sort are communicated more clearly; you could even inspect the value of `$d` after attempting instantiation, to verify that it was successful...

But why subclass PDO at all?  You can (and probably should) just use it directly:

```
$d = new PDO("mysql:host=127.0.0.1;port=8889;dbname=weddingplan", "root", "");
```

Comment: PHP tried to bail out. Yet the OP just don't let it go.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. actually nothing wrong that expect db connection with port 8889.

Answer (score 1):

If you're new to OOP, why would you create your own class, without enough experience in using other classes? It will do you no good at all. **Almost every line of your class is wrong.**

Instead, learn to use raw PDO. It's already a class, mind you, and not a bad one. It can do things way better than your home-brewed wrapper. Learn PDO first.

Answer (score 0):

Your example code appears to be different from your actual code, though your test method appears to be fine.

```
Warning: Creating default object from empty value in C:\xampp\htdocs\newwedding\models\class.db.php on line 18
```

A default object is an object with no constructor, ensure you're passing in parameters to your constructor and they are what they should be (e.g. not empty!)

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function test() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\newwedding\models\class.db.php on line 32
```

Your db object is null, and not what you think it is. You can't call a method on a null object!

Comment: Thanks you for the response

Comment: Please upvote and select as the answer if it helped you determine the problem with your code. My answer was posted before eggyal's!

Answer (score -3):

Replace this line:

```
parent::__construct($dsn, $user, $passwd, $options);
```

With this:

```
new PDO($dsn, $user, $passwd, $options);
```

Comment: why? Can you give some explanation as to the reasons, whys and wherefores of your answer?